# TSLINT with Angular CLI can you get it to fail a build

Tags: angular, tslint, codelyzer

I am using tslint/codelyzer with Angular 5 and Visual studio code.

Basically I want to configure things so when I do ng build OR ng serve there will be compile time errors if any tslint rules are broken. Is this possible?

Comment: that question is unclear. can you provide more info?

Comment: Have rephrased my question